# gaierror, [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed in django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to send mail from Django to Gmail but I am getting `gaierror` in my browser when I run my server

[image: gaierror]

Here is my *views.py* code

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.core.mail import send_mail
def mail(request):
    subject = "Real programmer contact"
    msg = "Congratulations for your success"
    to = "mail@example.org"
    res = send_mail(subject, msg, 'example@gmail.com', [to])
    if(res == 1):
        msg = "Mail Sent"
    else:
        msg = "Mail could not sent"
    return render(request, 'testapp/index.html',{'msg':msg})
```

Here is the *settings.py* code

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gamil.com'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'example@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'example'
```

Here is the HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>mail box</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    {{msg}}
  </body>
</html>
```

and lastly here is the *urls.py*

```
path('mail/',views.mail),
```

I am not able to resolve this problem.

Comment: I'm sorry to embarrass you, but I believe a simple typo is the source of your error: `EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gamil.com'`. You probably meant: `smtp.gmail.com`

Comment: It appears that you have posted sensitive/private information. Please reset your passwords and/or revoke API keys and tokens, as they are considered compromised when posted on the internet. If personally-identifiable information was posted, please [edit] out the info then flag your post for a moderator to redact the revisions.